# $R[x]$ has a subring isomorphic to $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Say $R$ is a commutative ring. Does there exists a subring of $R[x]$ that is isomorphic to $R$?

My approach would be to define the subring of $R[x]$ that generates $R$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Constant polynomials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ring of constant polynomials in $R[x]$ is isomorphic to $R$

Comment: But the crux of the matter is to *prove* that! See my answer for one easy way.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ The evaluation hom $\rm\:f(x)\to f(0)\:$ is $1$-$1$, onto, restricted to polynomials of degree zero.

Comment: ok. +1 for quick way.

Comment: @Bil: How is the function 1-1, since I can take $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be two different functions in $R[x]$ with the same constant term and the value of $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ will still be same. So, I don't understand how will it be 1-1?

Comment: @MUH  the claim is *restricted* to polynomials of degree zero (constants).